# Optimize SQL query (get rid of rows before sorting in SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a PostgreSQL server which is used as a database for a sub-realtime application.

Currently a particular table contains 2512742 rows of data, and is updated every minute.

This data is frequently pulled from the database which takes lots of time.

I have checked the explain analyze option in pgAdmin and it shows that the quarry is sorting and then filtering the data. Is there a way in which we could eliminate most of the rows and then sort the data?

I am sharing a sample SQL query for you to check.

```
SELECT * 
FROM symbolsdata 
WHERE symbol='BTCUSDT:Binance' 
  AND timestamp < '2023-01-01 00:00' 
  AND timeframe = '1h' 
  AND timestamp > '2022-12-01 00:00' 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

The explain analyze of this query:

```
#   Node    Timings Rows    Loops
Exclusive   Inclusive   Rows X  Actual  Plan
1.   Gather Merge (cost=233383.86..233441.73 rows=496 width=306) (actual=3677.511..3728.821 rows=743 loops=1)   152.695 ms  3728.821 ms ↓ 1.5   743 496 1
2.   Sort (cost=232383.84..232384.46 rows=248 width=306) (actual=3576.103..3576.126 rows=248 loops=3)   2384.199 ms 3576.126 ms ↑ 1 248 248 3
3.   Seq Scan on symbolsdata as symbolsdata (cost=0..232373.98 rows=248 width=306) (actual=1469.852..3575.782 rows=248 loops=3)
Filter: (("timestamp" < '2023-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" > '2022-12-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((symbol)::text = 'BTCUSDT:Binance'::text) AND ((timeframe)::text = '1h'::text))
Rows Removed by Filter: 837344
1191.928 ms 1191.928 ms ↑ 0.34  248 248 3
```

The table has 34 columns and I need to fetch all of them every time.

As we can see that server is sorting before filtering. According to me server can get rid of many rows then can sort.

I am not sure that this is possible but I need improvements as this query takes around 7.5 seconds, this adds up very much when it is in production as we need to fetch thousands of rows and need to do this fast.

I expect that I will get a optimal SQL query to perform this operation.

Edit->

column_names

"data_id"
"timestamp"
"symbol"
"timeframe"
"open"
"high"
"low"
"close"
"volume"
"marketchange"
"rsi"
"rsisma9"
"rsiema45"
"sma7"
"sma25"
"sma99"
"sma200"
"ema50"
"ema100"
"ema200"
"hma55"
"stochk"
"stochd"
"bb22u"
"bb22m"
"bb22l"
"td_seq_up"
"td_seq_dn"
"bbw"
"diff_close_ema200"
"supert"
"supert_direction"
"supert_long"
"supert_short"

Here `data_id` is a SERIAL and according to me this is an index.
Is there a way I could make it fast the program needs to fetch 10,000 (approx or more) rows each time?

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Worst of all, it's doing a full table scan (`Seq Scan`).

Comment: `create index ix1 on symbolsdata (symbol, timeframe, timestamp)` ?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions.

Comment: Don't look into the sequence in Explain Analyze, DB firstly uses filter and after then uses sorting data. Because you don't have indexes, so DB use Full Table Scan (see: filter and rows removed by filter). Add indexes and you will see the performance increase

Comment: I have added the column names should I also give the SQL for generating the table at first?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Does not address your issue but the contention that *server is sorting before filtering* is incorrect. The explain plan "runs" from the inside out and then "pipes" the  result of that step into the next higher step.  In your posted plan then it runs step 3, pipes result as input to step 2, then pipes that result as input to step 1. The **first step listed is always the last step executed**. Try this: Run the same explain within psql. Then notice the indentation at each level and the lack of line numbers. Those are an artifact of pgAdmin and are **not** form Postgres.